# How to run vpython program in Flask

Tags: python, flask, vpython

I want to run a vypthon simulation in Flask. I have no idea how, since a lot of different things I have tried always lead to errors.

This is just one example of many things I have tried:

```
from vpython import *
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/sfere')
def sfere():
    return sphere(color=color.red)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return redirect(url_for('sfere'))
```

The error I get in this case is:

```
ValueError
ValueError: signal only works in main thread of the main interpreter

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "C:\Users\princ\Dropbox\0 Projects\software\Flask\esther v2\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2091, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Users\princ\Dropbox\0 Projects\software\Flask\esther v2\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2076, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\princ\Dropbox\0 Projects\software\Flask\esther v2\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\princ\Dropbox\0 Projects\software\Flask\esther v2\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
            request_started.send(self)
            rv = self.preprocess_request()
            if rv is None:
                rv = self.dispatch_request()
        except Exception as e:
            rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
        return self.finalize_request(rv)
    
    def finalize_request(
        self,
        rv: t.Union[ResponseReturnValue, HTTPException],
File "C:\Users\princ\Dropbox\0 Projects\software\Flask\esther v2\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\princ\Dropbox\0 Projects\software\Flask\esther v2\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
File "C:\Users\princ\Dropbox\0 Projects\software\Flask\esther v2\app.py", line 9, in sfere
return sphere(color=color.red)
File "C:\Users\princ\Dropbox\0 Projects\software\Flask\esther v2\env\Lib\site-packages\vpython\vpython.py", line 1150, in __init__
super(sphere, self).setup(args)
File "C:\Users\princ\Dropbox\0 Projects\software\Flask\esther v2\env\Lib\site-packages\vpython\vpython.py", line 584, in setup
super(standardAttributes, self).__init__()
File "C:\Users\princ\Dropbox\0 Projects\software\Flask\esther v2\env\Lib\site-packages\vpython\vpython.py", line 240, in __init__
from .no_notebook import _
File "C:\Users\princ\Dropbox\0 Projects\software\Flask\esther v2\env\Lib\site-packages\vpython\no_notebook.py", line 55, in <module>
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
File "C:\Users\princ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\signal.py", line 47, in signal
handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
ValueError: signal only works in main thread of the main interpreter
```

Comment: I know nothing about Flask, but I would guess that there's a conflict between VPython's handling of events and Flask's handling of events.